# CLGeocoder Geocoding Requests Going Over Limit

Tags: ios, swift, clgeocoder

I'm trying to figure out ways to limit the amount of requests I make to the CLGeocoder because I keep on going over the maximum limit. I get the "**Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code = 2 "(null)**". Basically, everytime someone moves the map in the func regionDidChangeAnimated, I get that coordinate that they settle on, geocode to get the city/state and then hit my API, and then use those results to Geocode the new map pins in that region. Does anyone have any best practices to handle that kind of situation? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Function to see if user changed map region:**

```
private func mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction() -> Bool {
let view: UIView = self.mapView.subviews[0] as UIView
//  Look through gesture recognizers to determine whether this region change is from user interaction
if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
    for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
        if( recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended ) {
            return true
        }
    }
 }
  return false
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
mapChangedFromUserInteraction = mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction()
if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {
    // user changed map region

   }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {
    // user changed map region
    let center = mapView.centerCoordinate

    let mapLatitude = center.latitude
    let mapLongitude = center.longitude


     let locationmove = CLLocation(latitude: mapLatitude, longitude: mapLongitude)
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(locationmove) { (placemarks, error) in

        if (error != nil){

            print(error)

        }else {

            if let p = placemarks?[0]{

                let locality = p.locality ?? ""
                let administrativeArea = p.administrativeArea ?? ""


                 self.mappedCity = String(locality)
                 self.mappedState = String(administrativeArea)
                 self.parseJSON("\(locality)", state: "\(administrativeArea)")
            }

        } 

     }
   }
  }
```

**Function to parse JSON from Geocoded results:**

```
func parseJSON(city: String, state: String){
let passedCity = city
let passedState = state
let escapedCity = passedCity.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
let escapedState = passedState.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.API.com/api.php?city=\(escapedCity)&stateAbv=\(escapedState)&limit=10”)!

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (items, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {

        print(error)


    }else {


        if let items = items {


            do {
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(items, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                if jsonResult.count > 0 {

                    if let datas = jsonResult["data"] as? NSArray{

                        for data in datas{

                            if let title = data["title"] as? String {

                                if let street = data["street"] as? String {

                                    if let city =  data["city"] as? String {

                                        if let stateAbv =  data["stateAbv"] as? String {

                                            if let zip =  data["zip"] as? String {

                                                self.geoAddress("\(title)", street: "\(street)", city: "\(city)", state: "\(stateAbv)", zip: "\(zip)")


                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch{}


        }


    }

 }

 task.resume()

}


func geoAddress(title: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String){
let storeName = "\(title)"
let location = "\(street) \(city) \(state) \(zip)"
let geocoder = CLGeocoder();
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print("Error \(error!)")
    } else if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {

        let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate

        let pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        pointAnnotation.coordinate = coordinates
        pointAnnotation.title = storeName
        pointAnnotation.subtitle = location

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)

     }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the updated location with the old one, hence the distance you will get should be sufficiently high to make another `CLGeocoder` request.
Apple's documentation says that

- When you want to update the user’s current location automatically
  (such as when the user is moving), issue new geocoding requests only
  when the user has moved a significant distance and after a reasonable
  amount of time has passed. For example, in a typical situation, you
  should not send more than one geocoding request per minute.

  Go through the official documentation of [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/) for more info.